# Reflection performance and interface

Tags: .net, reflection, interface

I heard on Jeremy Clark's pluralsight session on Reflection that performance of reflection can be increased by programming to interface.

That video doesn't explain why and how -- Can someone provide me pointers on why and how interfaces improve reflection performance

Comment: You should at least edit your post to include a link to a video of the session. If that's not possible (or if you are so inclined), a quotation would be even better.

Comment: Maybe in a particular situation that Jeremy is doing in the session reflection can be replaced with programming to an interface, but AFAIK that's not the general case. I.e. you cannot always replace reflection with programming to an interface.

Comment: BTW, reflection has it's place in .NET, but I saw sooo many examples of it's abuse. Remember Reflection is very powerful, you can do almost anything you want and because of that can be abused. Also calling a method with reflection is orders of magnitude slower than calling a method directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Slide 23](http://www.jeremybytes.com/Downloads/Slides-PracticalReflection.pdf) from Jeremy's "*[Practical Reflection in .NET](http://www.jeremybytes.com/Demos.aspx#PR)*" lecture (given in January, 2014), the following is presented:

> - **Cast Types to a Known Interface**
>     All method calls go through the interface
>     No dynamic method calls –no MethodInfo.Invoke
>     Avoid interacting with private members

The basic idea is that it's better to use Reflection to find classes which implement a known interface then it is to find and directly use individual methods and properties. The reason?

1. The fewer Reflection calls you have to make, the better. Each call to Reflection costs a lot of time (relatively speaking). It's much more effecient to make a single call to Reflection to get a class which implements a known Interface (from which point you can access members via the Interface) then it is to access each and every member via reflection.
2. You can be reasonably confident that the class members associated with a known interface will behave in a particular way and not cause dangerous side effects. Arbitrarily grabbing methods and properties from a class based only on the name is extremely dangerous when dealing with third-party assemblies - you can't be reasonably certain that the method was meant to be used by you for your purpose.

Comment: This is basically using reflection for discovery. But you cannot use this approach always. Sometime a class doesn't implement the interface that gives you what you need. But this is a good advice when possible.

Comment: @PetarRepac - I am just attempting to explain what Jeremy Clark was getting on about. Of course one approach is never going to work for all scenarios.

Comment: @JDB -- Appreciate your response, it explains how programming to interface reduces cost(in terms of performance) of reflection.

Comment: @JDB - I understand that. Just wanted to make clear that this can be done just under some circumstances. BTW, seems that same approach should also work with base classes, not only with interfaces. Sometimes I can cast to a common base class even when I don't have a common interface to work with.